# Ripple effect cannot cover the whole textview after canvas.translate

Tags: android, canvas, ripple

I used canvas.translate(dx, dy) method to move the canvas to make the DrawableLeft icon align with text in a textview. All work perfectly but when I added Ripple effect by setting android:background=selectableItemBackground(It's correct ignore the spelling or something), it cannot cover the whole textview but the position starting from the icon. What should I do for that? I tried Borderless ripple but not working.

Comment: You can try for android:foreground instead of android:background.

Comment: @VivekBarai tried not working